# Could a low cost gliding bomb go through modern military defences?

Tags: weapons

A warfare that involves nations with a little military budget. One of the two decides to build gliders made out of fibreglass because it is transparent to radio and radar waves. The glider in mounted on top of a solid fuel rocket with the wings folded. The explosive is not completely transparent, but it is a gel with a small signature. The only components with a high signature are the mechanism to fold the wing, the electronic guidance and the fuse. They are small parts and shielded as much as possible. The shielding is made out of flat plastic plates coated with carbon black. Flaps are moved by hydraulic actuators, the pipes are made of fibreglass and the fluid is silicone oil. So overall there will be only a faint signature without the advanced technologies used in fifth generation military planes.

BTW, fibreglass cannot pierce armours, but the explosive in the glider is arranged in a shaped charge.

The solid fuel booster is more visible, therefore it burns as quickly as possible, brings the glider over the height of 20000 meters, than it detaches. It opens its own wings and glides as well to act as a decoy. It also lights a couple of flares.

Apart from the fact that the range of such weapons will be limited and that it can be used only at night. With no heat signature and almost no radar signature can it go through modern military defences?

Comment: This is arguably not really worldbuilding, it's threat assessment against unspecified "modern" anti-air defences.  Have you done any research at all on how low-signature drones have fared, for example when used by both sides in Ukraine? (Hint:  there are drones with cardboard bodies out there.)  You also have not specified how big the glider is and what payload it is carrying - anti-personnel, anti-armour or a bunker buster?

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Drones have a motor. They may have a low radar signature, but not as low as gliders could have. Furthermore, many are built using composites because they are meant to have a stronger structure and longer service life, but composites are not transparent to radars.

Comment: Shaped charges require a significant amount of dense metal which will weigh down your glider considerably.

Comment: @FluidCode How do you plan to guide the explosive charge where you want without an engine? How is it seeing where it should go? It looks like you are still missing some points in your design that might complicate it's "non-detection" ^^.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 use-of-technology questions have been permissible on [worldbuilding.se] almost since the beginning.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Fun fact: A heavier glider can glide farther and faster from the same height than the same glider with less weight.  Gliders are interesting!

Comment: @JBH I understand that questions like this get through, but I'll argue that they shouldn't when there are various sites and discussions (eg https://www.navalgazing.net/The-Drone-Revolution ) dedicated to exactly this sort of real-world topic.  More importantly, the OP still has not edited the question to specify whether these gliders are 1 kg anti-personnel or 1 ton bunker busters or somewhere in between, which makes a huge difference in determining the "best" answer.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 That's a good question to ask in [meta]. But until the policy is changed, [real-world questions are permitted here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609). I initially supported the policy. Now I hate it. It's had (IMO) a decidedly negative impact on the stack, driving it to be physics-lite rather than worldbuilding. I've tried to change it, but I've gained no real support. You're welcome to take a shot at it. I'll support you. But until that policy changes, this question is on-topic.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 One more note. Until 24 hours have gone by (only 10 have at this point), it's not fair to complain that the OP hasn't made changes. For all we know the OP is asleep. FluidCode? Next time you're on, Kerr has a good point. Please clarify the statistics of your gliders and bombs. Cheers.

Comment: Massive manouvering / direction change at very high g, Spoofing, Swarm,  Multiple warhead with all these, More money :-)

Comment: @JBH *"More importantly, the OP still has not edited the question to specify whether these gliders are 1 kg anti-personnel or 1 ton bunker busters or somewhere in between, "* I was offline, I just logged in. But I'll keep the question as it is because I think that that part is not so relevant. I could just note that they cannot be bunker buster because they carry no piercing material, but they could still carry bombs in the range of few hundreds of kilograms.

Comment: @FluidCode Many querents try to keep their questions as general as possible believing it'll produce more answers with greater variety to choose from. It's a mistake. Kerr is right, there's a huge difference in the nature of the glider that must only carry a 1kg bomb vs. one that must carry a metric tonne (just as there's a difference between fighter jets and bombers...). It affects the glider's size, maximum altitude, and maximum gliding distance - and therefore, it's detectability. It's your choice, but I agree with Kerr that the detail is necessary. I know you've selected your answer...

Comment: ...but radar can detect the bunker buster bomb, and so the answer is incomplete unless you assume only small bombs will be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Invisible to Radars, not to Lidars**

If the enemy is equipped with the current equipment and is not aware of the new weapon a first surprise attack might go through. Current radars, even multi-frequency radars are not tuned to detect them, they would get only a faint signal. Though, thereafter the enemy might equip themselves with [Lidars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar) using lasers in the visible range. Then all the gliders will be easily shot down.

A good quality lidar mounted on a truck will cover a smaller area than a radar, but given the slow speed of the gliders it will be enough. Then some missiles made with the cheapest technologies, guided from below and using for the final approach simple laser ranging devices which are cheaper than lidars can shoot them down. Also a drone equipped with an onboard lidar and a 20 mm autocannon could easily shoot them down at a low cost.

Comment: Lidar as all things laser and light fails in all sorts of weather conditions : rain, fog, snow, dust storm. It also allows for meta material stealth

Answer (score 9):

**Alone, no**

Today's military defences involve radars in more than a single range of frequencies. Meter-long, centimeter-long, millimeter-long radars exist and are covering areas independently, leading to (ideally) all areas covered by radars of all of those frequencies. Fiberglass might be a good thing that has a low visibility in visible light, but at least one of those wavelengths would be reflected well enough to notice that glider by one of the radars. And once it's detected, it's a matter of time until it'll be shot down. A single decoy would not help, it's just two targets instead of one.

**In great numbers, quite possibly**

Check the latest missile attack on Israel - HAMAS have *overloaded* Israeli anti-air defence with sheer number of incoming warheads, of course a lot of them passed the perimeter and wrecked havoc at where they were aiming. If you'd launch several thousands of those things, you might be pretty sure a percentage of them would pass through because of SAM running out of ammo, if not for other reasons like swarm tactics on those gliders, some clever use of one-time accelerators post-launch, or plain attacking with standard missiles, in the same numbers.

Your device is too slow to afford high-level flight, even if launched into the heights, and having it be transparent won't do much. Instead, add a propeller to its nose and have it travel like a winged rocket, close to the ground, potentially even between obstacles like trees, then radars might not be a good device to discern those, as they would be "below horizon" for them, radars are usually tuned to not scan the land as there would be too many false detections in those sectors. With this set-up you would have a greater chance of hitting some edge target from the global set of them, as visual detection would be the most reliable method of detecting your unpiloted airplane, it won't leave them a lot of time to react.

Comment: I agree that gliders moving slowly are an easy target. However when you say "*but at least one of those wavelengths would be reflected well*" you should check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radome)

Comment: @FluidCode I am aware of these, but these cover radars of millimeter-long waves, with phased grid lattice antennae, I was talking more about [this kind of radars](https://topwar.ru/60556-s-400-sbivaet-lyuboy-stels.html) (the lowermost picture with 3 radars, the rightmost runs on meter-long waves and can detect fiberglass). AFAIK fiberglass is indeed transparent to 3.0GHz plus microwave range, but there are longer waves used in radars which circumvent most of the stealth measures invented today, including fiberglass hulls.

Comment: I am not aware of this being false, however I'm not able to find public data on how fiberglass interacts with meter-long radio waves. Yet I do remember that in Serbian wars anti-air had detected US stealth bombers using exactly meter-long wave radars, while centimeter-long devices fell short. Thus it seems plausible that at least one wavelength range of existing radars *will* catch this glider. (Also it's slow as heck, allowing more time to detect it, while being passive definitely helps)

Comment: @FluidCode Your link clearly states: "...depending on the particular application, using various construction materials such as fiberglass, polytetrafluoroethylene (PTFE)-coated fabric, and others..." meaning that the construction material of each radome is specific to the radar's wave length.  When you line up 3 radomes made of different materials transmitting different wavelengths, you composite the outputs of these sensors and are able to see all 3 materials on from thier composite.

Comment: You can scan on land with doppler radar.  It ignores any signal that comes back exactly on the transmitting frequency.  And flying it through the trees means a guidance system that can plot a route around the trees--not exactly a low-cost weapon.

Comment: The thing that overwhelmed the automatic defense system wasn't rockets it was gliders with people, very low if any radar signature, no outgoing or incoming transmissions. As well as well, bad intelligence.

Comment: 'Instead, add a propeller to its nose and have it travel like a winged rocket, close to the ground, potentially even between obstacles like trees', Congratulations, you've just invented the cruise missile, except real missiles use turbines because that gets you better range and speed.

Comment: Fiberglass isn't a good reflector at any radio wavelength. It's basically transparent at some frequencies and absorbent at others. The ranges where it absorbs make it a bad radome, certainly, but not a bad stealth material. Pieces of it less than 10cm thick are certainly not going to generate much return at a 1m wavelength, with a dielectric constant of only about 4.

Answer (score 7):

### Depending on your definition of "Modern", they could be detected, and relatively easy to counter

The military grade radar systems being produced right now tend to be is spectrographic, meaning that it is not just detecting for how strong of a radar signal something has, but what combination of wavelengths are being reflected back.  By transmitting on many wavelengths, the radar system can determine based on what wavelengths are and are not reflected back a lot about the material that the object is made out of.  Because of this, radar can tell the difference between a bird and fiberglass bodied object because they have different spectrographic properties.  If any flying object with a spectrographic and behavioral profile that is not that of a bird were to be detected on an intercept course for a target of military value without prior air-space clearance, then it would most likely be shot down.

#### Even in great numbers, they would do poorly compared to regular missiles

Furthermore, gliders are WAY slower than typical missiles.  Shooting down a high-speed ballistic missile is best done with another high speed missile which is both expensive to make and takes up a lot of space.  So, air defenses typically have a limited number of interceptor missiles they can deploy. However, slower rockets and drones are much easier to deal with en masse, as long as you don't need to cover too large of an area.  A modern AA gun like the [Phalanx CIWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanx_CIWS) is an auto-targeting machinegun with up to hundreds of thousands of rounds of ammo that can fire at a rate of 4,500 rounds/minute with a high degree of accuracy at ranges of up to 6km (or 2km if using self-detonating HEI rounds to minimize collateral damage). Slow moving gliders are very easy to hit; so, it only takes a fraction of a second for this weapon to fire a kill shoot before re-aiming on the next target.  A single one of these AA guns could realistically shoot down 5-20 times as many of these gliders as they could regular missiles.

#### ... unless you mean slightly less than modern radar/air defense

While the high end-radar systems being created by many countries today are spectrographic systems integrated directly into AI powered AA grids, most countries are still using a significant number of radar and defense systems that are many decades old. So if you were to attack an older military installation, one belonging to a less advanced nation, or a small forward base that may not have then infrastructure for a complex AA system, then this strategy has a good chance of success.

This is because most older radar systems don't reach into the wavelengths necessary to see such drones, and even if they do, they don't have the computer systems to tell the difference between fiberglass and feathers.  And even if they could identify the threat well, many lack high speed auto-targeting AA guns for dealing with swarm tactics.

A prime example of this are the plastic and cardboard drones that have seen a lot of success in the Ukraine/Russia war where the typical level of technology available is 20+ years behind what you would expect going after a more modernized military target, and the front-lines don't see heavy use of the most advanced technology either side has at thier disposal because artillery has rendered deployment of high powered active radar systems to the front line too dangerous meaning that many compounds have nothing more than wetware powered defenses when it comes to drone strikes.

Comment: Re shooting down a glider, I recall that in WWII old wooden I-16 planes were sometimes (not always ofc) returning to base perforated into a cullender, almost literally (100+ holes in hull and wings). A properly built drone would also not fall down from a single hole made by CIWS, unless its payload would detonate. Yet, modern AA is built against *missiles*, such slow-moving targets might be difficult to shoot down without some less-than-modern devices like flak cannons, which are better vs these than AA missiles. Yes machine guns would also do, although IMO flak would fare better.

Comment: @Vesper, the difference here is that a glider plane is mostly hollow spaces and a glider bomb is mostly high explosives which the HEI rounds used by anti-missle AA guns are specifically designed to detonate.    Also, slow is always easier to hit than fast.  The same targeting algorithms are used, but your margin of error becomes smaller the slower something is.

Comment: ...that said, using hallow decoys might be helpful for holding AA gun locks.  If they can't confirm the kill, then they may just keep firing until they turn the glider to swiss-cheese giving the actual bombs more time to close the gap.

Comment: Well, should agree, unless the targetting algorithm would not get stuck on a decoy glider which won't explode upon being hit to where is the payload on a normal one. Decoys are pretty powerful vs single-target weaponry like a machine gun, you waste shots and time on a decoy while real warheads fly by. Even if an algo would be deciding the current target is a decoy after it being hit, it's still 50% wasted resources. That's why I say any AA can be overloaded with enough warheads.

Comment: Heh by the way, a terminology difference. You have "turn into swiss cheese", we have "turn into a cullender" (literal translation) XD

Comment: Also worth noting 1) that a glider by definition needs a large wing surface, which makes it more detectable; and 2) that even mediocre gliders have glide ratios of 20+, which means that these weapons are slowly gliding in from 400+ km from their target, with a whole host of consequences.

Comment: @Vesper Haha, I was actually wondering as I wrote that sentence if it would make since to people where they call it emmental cheese... but decided to keep the colloquialism for simplicity sake.

Comment: Your Phalanx can't shoot down a swarm because it will run out of ammo.  The latest version has only 20 seconds of ammo and it's going to fire until the target is down--any given target is going to be engaged with at least 2x the flight time of the rounds plus whatever time it takes the radar to verify destruction.

Comment: @Vesper In NZ. We have "Swiss Cheese" AND Collander as metaphors. Also just "shoot it full of holes". Also maybe "like a sieve". We are flexible and diverse :-).

Comment: @LorenPechtel The older designs could hold enough ammo for 55 seconds of sustained fire but it was found to be tactically wasteful because they overheat after just a few seconds of sustained fire; so, newer ships use more guns with less ammo each.   In original experiments, the Phalanx  using sustained fire until confirmed kill could only shoot down about 5-6 drones. However, I can find several references to Phalanx systems being reprogrammed to deal with drone swarms, but the results seem to all be classified

Comment: ... but what is not classified is that since then, they have been given a 1000 round burst option.  If we assume the "target accurate" doctrine was a part of this choice, then the system should be at least 50% accurate at it's listed maximum effective range.  So, we can infer that a single modernized phalanx should be able to shoot down somewhere between 45-90 drones with a single load of ammo.  Since a glider takes several minutes to cross a phalanx's kill zone, it is likely that the gun will have no problem using up all its ammo in burst fire mode before the first impact.

Comment: When dealing with slow targets, you do not need to wait to confirm the kill.  You can fire several bursts at different targets before actually confirming the kill on the first target because you have time to try again in case you missed the first time.

Comment: CWIS has a max effective range of ~1,400 m. Which means it's really easy to fly over it and on to a different target.

Comment: @codeMonkey the question asks if it "go through modern military defences" not if it can go over.  If you want to hit a random school or hospital, then sure, bombs away, but to hit a naval base or ship, you have to go into the kill zone. As for the kill zone, wikipedia is citing the specs of the originals 1980s weapon system.  The Block 1B Naval version has an effective range of 3.6km vs small fast moving missiles and the ground version is target accurate all the way up to the 2km range at which its HEI rounds self destruct to prevent collateral damage.

Comment: 6km is the range at which the naval version can engage larger slower missiles and aircraft. Since gliders are so slow, I would expect the maximum of this range to apply... though yes, if we are talking about the ground defense version, a closer estimation is more appropriate,  I will add this to the answer

Comment: @Nosajimiki - taking the current Russian invasion of Ukraine as our model, Russia would need thousands of CWIS units (even assuming a 6km effective range) to defend their front lines, close in logistics, airfields, and manufacturing centers from a low cost cruise missile equivalent. Flying over the front line CWIS to hit the undefended airfield is absolutely "going through" their air defense system.

Comment: @codeMonkey read my 3rd section more closely. I've already addressed this.  AA guns are generally not put on the front line, but in direct proximity of high profile targets like airfields, command centers, and logistic depots, etc.

Comment: @Nosajimiki It's not that they put fewer rounds in the new versions, it's that they upped the fire rate so it burns through it's ammo faster.  I wasn't aware of the overheating issue but it sure sounds like it would reduce the number of gliders that could be hit.  It's built to kill one or two inbound missiles and in that role you would like it to survive but it's worthwhile even if it destroys itself in firing.

Answer (score 4):

### For a Little While

Most existing anti-air systems are keyed towards missiles, rockets, and jets - anything that has radar profile significantly different from those objects will likely get through. It's not enough that some radar can see the glider, it needs to be a radar that's attached to a weapon system. (eg, the seeker at the end of the missile needs to see the target or it can't home!)

But the kill-chains will adjust over time. How quickly they adjust is probably directly related to how effectively you use the gliders.

### Saturation

The issue with missile defense is always the cost. If your gliders cost 20,000, and the missile that kills it costs 2,000,000 - well that's a problem for the defender. This problem is worse if you concentrate fire, and locally deplete the enemies resources. Then your gliders start getting through even a purpose designed anti-glider system.

This could be worse if you launch multiple gliders from one rocket; you've lowered the per unit cost of your gliders by using a single launch vehicle. This effectively repurposes the concept of [MIRV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_independently_targetable_reentry_vehicle) but for non-ballistic weapons.

Comment: Other answers point out that a slow glider can be taken out by relatively cheap bullets from an auto-targeting turret, which is a thing that already exists.

Comment: This is why Israel built the Iron Dome system--it's optimized for a low cost per round, it doesn't need to be able to play EW games because it's targets have no ability to defend themselves.

Comment: @LorenPechtel : and even the Iron Dome doesn't have a 100% success rate. Throw enough projectiles against it, and at lease *some* of them will get through.

Comment: @vsz the projectiles that get through are small, fast-moving dense objects, like artillery rounds. That's rather different to a big slow glider.

Comment: @PeterCordes - CWIS has a max range of ~1,400 meters, which means it's a point defense. Great for defending a ship, but to defend, say, the existing front in the Russia / Ukraine conflict which is dozens of miles deep by hundreds on miles long you'd need ** THOUSANDS** of them. There's a reason why low cost, plastic quad-copters are currently very effective in that conflict.

Comment: @PeterCordes - to put hard numbers, assume you're dealing with a 50 mile by 250 mile area to defend (front line where troops are plus the nearby logistics support areas) then that's 12,500 square miles. If the CWIS has a 1,000 m effective radius, it's roughly covering 1 square mile. Your defender would need 10,000+ CWIS units to support it's war effort -- more, if you assume that the gliders have capability to attack further than 50 miles to strike further back logistics or manufacturing centers. Probably not realistic. And again, local saturation could leave important areas undefended.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, fiberglass is indeed a material difficult to detect for the radars, the downside is that it is not transparent to visible light.

OP is aware that slow moving gliders are easy targets and limited the use to night attacks, but night vision equipment can easily see them, the defenders can aim their weapons manually, in the future the aim can be automated with some image processing. You just need a hood to shield the lens of the night vision equipment from the light coming from below and the silhouette would appear against the background of the stars. If the night is cloudy it's even better, the clouds reflect the light coming from below and would make the gliders visible enough.

This leaves only the possibility to attack when it is cloudy and there is no light from below. The only possible targets could be a ship in the middle of the sea or an isolated target in the middle of a wasteland, but those targets could simply use searchlights.

Final point there is no need to keep the men constantly on guard or the searchlights constantly switched on. When a radar detects a booster missile going up it can send an alarm and put the potential targets on alert. Given the slow speed the gliders can be shot down at close range by heavy machine guns.

Comment: Re booster detection, gliders usually have a high aerodynamic quality, thus are likely capable of reaching 1000 kilometers downwind, as OP says they are launched 20 km high. You can't see the booster burn from such a distance.

Comment: @Vesper Glide ratios goes out the window at heights of 20km where the atmosphere is only 5% of the density at sea level.  It will do a lot more falling than gliding until it gets to an altitude of 5-10km.  A realistic maximum range is probably closer to 200-300km.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, it's called a Glide Bomb.

[Glide bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glide_bomb) are tactical stand off weapons designed to hit well-defended, stationary targets. They're unpowered bombs with guidance and wings; they're often misrepresented as "guided missiles" but they lack propulsion. They're dropped from an aircraft moving at combat speed and from high altitude, the aircraft serves a function similar to your rocket booster.

Because they're small and unpowered they are very difficult to detect and hit. The best defense is to take out the launching aircraft, which may itself be stealthy.

One example is the [AGM-154 Joint Standoff Weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGM-154_Joint_Standoff_Weapon) aka the JSOW.

[image]
[image]

JSOW weighs about 475 kg (1000 lb) and delivers about 225 kg of payload. When dropped from 40,000 feet (12,000 meters) it can glide 130km. It uses relatively cheap [GPS and inertial guidance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS/INS) to hit stationary targets. This gives us a rough idea of the performance characteristics of your proposed glider.

## Air launch vs ground launch

Your proposed booster rocket powered glide bomb has several drawbacks...

- It must be launched from a ground launch vehicle limiting its operational area.
- The launch will create significant flash and smoke inviting [counter-battery fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-battery_fire) and an indication that hey, there's a bomb on the way.

With a booster you can, theoretically, make the bomb as big as you like, and launch it as high as you like. But make it too big and now it can be detected and shot down. Make it too fast or launch it too high and now it has to be strengthened to handle higher stresses compromising stealth.

Eventually you'll reinvent the [ballistic missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_missile).

Answer (score 0):

It might work, for a little while. At first, when the existence of the weapon isn't suspected, it will likely be filtered out by the computers guiding the air defenses because it's not recognised as a threat. But as soon as people start putting two and two together and figuring out what's hitting them, they'll reprogram those computers and WILL be able to detect and target your gliding bombs.

That's basically what happened with the Japanese kamikaze attacks at the end of WW2 as well. For the first few weeks they were quite successful, as the US AAA crews weren't trying to shoot down Japanese aircraft so much as damage them so they had to break off their attacks. But the Japanese kamikazes didn't break off their attacks, they kept going despite the damage. As soon as word got around the US crews would keep firing until the attacking aircraft exploded or crashed into the sea, mostly negating the kamikaze threat.

Similar with any new weapon. The German Fritz-X glide bomb wasn't recognised as a threat at first but once recognised for what it was it was relatively easy to negate or at least avoid by the ships it was designed to attack and the Germans relegated it to attacking stationary targets like bridges instead that couldn't evade.

Currently Ukraine is using a lot of drones with small warheads, but they've just about lost their effectiveness because Soviet/Russian air defenses now know what to look for and engage. Some still get through but not nearly the numbers that used to, basically (as with the Japanese kamikazes) it requires a saturation attack. The Ukrainian unmanned bomb boats are starting to face a similar obstacle to reach Soviet/Russian ships, making them less effective (and those are far more expensive to build than little flying ones, plus larger and thus harder to hide).

Yemeni terrorists used to use drones and crude ballistic missiles against Saudi Arabia, until the Saudi armed forces figured out what was happening and now they have a pretty solid air defense set up that negates that threat.

Hamas and PLO terrorists did something similar against Israel, leading to Israel developing and deploying Iron Dome very quickly that intercepts most of the incoming weapons (and even mortar rounds at times).

And that's always the case, one side develops a weapons system, the other side for a little while doesn't have a response but quickly develops one (especially if the other side is technologically equal or superior, a far inferior opponent may lack the technology to field a viable response, think the use of aircraft by Italy in 1920s/30s Ethiopia against tribal rebellion, rebels who had only spears and knives).